# Does Continuous projections imply complementation?

Tags: functional-analysis

(This is a possibly trivial question.)

Let $B$ be a Banach space for which there exists a continuous projection from $B$ onto a closed subspace $X\subseteq B$.

> **Question.** Does there exist a closed subspace $Y\subseteq B$ such that 
>   $$
> X\cap Y=\{0\}\,\,\text{ and }\,\,X+Y=B?
> $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, take $Y=\{x-Px:x \in B\}$. Then any point $x \in B$ is $Px + (x-Px) \in X+Y$. If $x \in X \cap Y$ then $x=Pz$ for some $z$. Since $P^{2}=P$ we see that $P$ vanishes on $Y$. Hence $Pz=0$ so $x=0$. Finally we have to show that $Y$ is closed.  Let $x_n-Px_n \to u$. Since $P$ is continuous we get $$0=Px_n-P^{2}x_n=P(x_n-Px_n) \to Pu.$$ Thus $Pu=0$ and $u=u-Pu \in Y$. Hence $Y$ is closed.

Comment: You could say the whole thing I think more simply by just saying $Y$ is the kernel of $P$.

Comment: @ David C. Ullrich yes, of course, $Y$ is the kernel of $P$. Thanks for the comment.